# Why is Motional Emf 0 when velocity is parallel to length?

Tags: electromagnetic-induction

Why is  Motional Emf 0 when velocity is parallel to length?

Lets assume a case when B (magnetic field) is perpendicular to velocity and parallel to area vector of a circular coil . Now according to formula Motional Emf =

$$V=\int (\vec v\times \vec B)\cdot d\vec \ell$$

My book states that no emf is produce when velocity is parallel to length (dl) but i fail to understand why (as there is no relation that i can see in the formula) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the velocity is in cross product with the magnetic field, the result of the parenthesis will be perpendicular to the velocity, so the parenthesis will be perpendicular to the length, that is parallel to the velocity, giving zero as result.